# Converting a xml DOM structure form a file into a dictionary in python

Tags: python

i have a file , not actually an xml file , but a text file which looks something like this (example.txt)-

```
<01-01-20>
hello hello . . random content
</01-01-20>


<04-01-20>
hello again. . some more random content.....

</04-01-20>
```

I would like to store the values in the text file as key value pair in dictionary , something like:

```
{<01-01-20>:"hello hello. . ",<04-01-20>:"hello again.. . "}
```

Is this possible. Please guide me on how to do this in python

EDIT -

THE CODE I CAME UP WITH ,

```
import re
import mmap

tf1 = open('text1.txt', 'r+b')  ##first kosha
tf2 = open('text2.txt', 'r')  ##second kosha

first = []
second = []
reg = re.compile("^<.*>$")     ##sample regular expression for < >
for line in tf1:
    first += reg.findall(line)

for line in tf2:
    second += reg.findall(line)

print('Tags that are present in file 1 but not in file2')    
for i in first:
    if i not in second:
        print(i)




tf1.close()
tf2.close()
```

Now i need to compare the hyms from both text files and tell if they are alike or not , so i figured it'd be better to put it into a dictionary.
Please help.

Comment: That's not valid XML. The easiest way is to change how this file is generated, to something like `<text date="01-01-20">hello helloo</text>` Then you can use any parser.

Comment: Yes sir , i agree it's not a proper xml , its a text file where the recital numbers or page:stanza numbers of a particular hymn is stored in the <tag> follwed by the hymn.

Comment: This can be done without using an XML parser because its a rather simple case...but it makes me wonder if this is a homework assignment or something, so think it better maybe for you to provide your own first go at the problem in code and if you get stuck then ask for help.

Comment: Sir , please help . i came up with this one particular piece of code myself but found it more easier to deal with the data if it were stored in a dictionary. 
and no , it is not a homework , im scraping it off a webpage. please help

Comment: Please don't deciede things yourself , please teach / help someone in times of need and they will remember you for your good deed. I wouldn't have taken the time out to type everything lest i hadn't given it my own try. Kind sir , please help me.

Comment: "i came up with this one particular piece of code myself ..." -- but you haven't shown your code yet. Post what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the full code you actually are expecting.

**Code**

```
with open("file_in.txt", "r") as file:
    dict1 = {}
    lines = file.readlines()
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        try:
            if lines[i].startswith('<') and lines[i+1] != '\n':
                dict1[lines[i].strip()] = lines[i+1].strip()
        except:
            print("File read complete!")
    
print(dict1)
```

**Output**

```
{'<01-01-20>': 'hello hello . . random content', '<04-01-20>': 'hello again. . some more random content.....'}
```

Comment: Sir , i will be honest , i will try your code and explore other options from it as well. Thank you very much for your time. You have atleast instilled some hope. thank you

Comment: You are welcome! I checked it out on my own machine with your input file and got the output that I shared with you. It'll work hopefully.

Comment: Yes sir , again thank you very much. This encourages me to learn more.